# SLURM's sinfo displays mixed instead of allocated state

Tags: state, slurm

I am using SLURM job manager for dispatching jobs in a Linux cluster running Ubuntu Server 14.04.3. I noticed that sinfo reports all nodes in mixed mode whether they are partially or fully allocated; idle nodes are correctly reported as idle. Below is the output of sinfo command:

```
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
compute*     up   infinite      5    mix node[01-05]
compute*     up   infinite      1   idle node06
```

However, node04 is fully allocated and therefore its state should be reported as alloc by sinfo, while node03 is partially allocated as can be seen using scontrol command:

```
scontrol show node node04
CPUAlloc=6 CPUErr=0 CPUTot=6 CPULoad=6.01 Features=(null)
Gres=(null)
NodeAddr=node04 NodeHostName=node04
OS=Linux RealMemory=64333 AllocMem=0 Sockets=1 Boards=1
State=ALLOCATED ThreadsPerCore=1 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1
BootTime=2016-04-11T16:38:52 SlurmdStartTime=2016-04-11T16:39:59
CurrentWatts=0 LowestJoules=0 ConsumedJoules=0
ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s

scontrol show node node03    
CPUAlloc=1 CPUErr=0 CPUTot=6 CPULoad=1.01 Features=(null)
Gres=(null)
NodeAddr=node03 NodeHostName=node03
OS=Linux RealMemory=64333 AllocMem=0 Sockets=1 Boards=1
State=MIXED ThreadsPerCore=1 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1
BootTime=2016-04-11T16:38:38 SlurmdStartTime=2016-04-11T16:39:08
CurrentWatts=0 LowestJoules=0 ConsumedJoules=0
ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s
```

What is wrong with sinfo?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else has the some issue, this has been resolved a couple of years ago:

https://bugs.schedmd.com/show_bug.cgi?id=611

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) the answer as you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.